# How to save directly to the persistent store, without holding the data into memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I have an app that downloads some documents from a server and saves them into a persistent store (Sqlite). I hold the documents data in a `NSData` property of a `NSManagedObject` and everytime I download a new doc, basically the app saves the data to the persistent store, but also keeps it in memory, which I don't want. Is there a way to force faulting? Somehow, I would like to release the memory, and keep the data only in the database. Hope it makes sense, I'm a beginner with Core Data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn a NSManagedObject into fault by calling [refreshObject:mergeChanges:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/refreshObject%3amergeChanges%3a).

Comment: +1 This is the proper way to force a `NSManagedObject` to a fault.

Comment: This, combined with "Allows external storage" solved the problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to read it into one or more managed objects that are local to the scope of a routine, and then when they go out of scope they will be released from memory.  (Might want to save them first).